# Configure HTTP Access to Analysis Services - Won't work with basic authentication

Tags: http, iis, ssas

Followed the instructions in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx
SSAS is running on a hosted server. No domain.
Able to connect with anonymous authentication, but when basic is enabled, neither SSMS or Excel will connect. 
Error from SSMS is "The remote server returned an error (401). Unauthorized"
Credentials are set up on the remote machine as DOMAIN:443
Credentials have admin privileges on the server.

Excel says "connection cannot be made to remote machine or SSAS is not running"

HTTP or HTTPS doesn't matter.

When it connects with anonymous, no cubes are returned so it is apparently doing nothing with the userid/password.  Just connecting.

When I connect via port 2383 using the same credentials, I have no problem in SSMS or Excel.

Help is GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was partially solved by starting over and following the steps in this article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx

Honestly, I can't pin down the exact resolution, but I believe it has to do with using a different folder structure (other than inetpub/wwwroot...) on my D drive and therefore losing the standard security configuration.
I created an OLAP folder on C:/inetpub/wwwroot and it works... with the exception of SSL which still does not work.

HTTP connects fine, but not HTTPS.  Still working on that.